# Force return values to be saved in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, save, return

Is there a way in VB.net to force someone to save a value returned from a function?

Here's the reason:
I work with databases, and we have created a function to credit a person's account. However, we want to see the results before we commit them to the database:

```
Dim trans as List(Of Transaction) = Transaction.createCredit(agreement_id, amount)
```

However, we don't want anyone at our company to think that the `createCredit` function will also commit the transactions to the database. Is there a way to ensure that they save the return value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to force function return value to be collected by the caller.

This is not VB.NET specific behavior, it works in C# the same way. So this is perfectly valid syntax in VB.NET, with no warnings or errors:

```
Sub Main()
  X()
End Sub

Function X()
  Return 0
End Function
```

What you need is coding standards, unfortunately, you cannot force coding standards, you can only **agree** on them. There has to be mutual understanding and agreement in this, before you see any benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

you could rise an event at the end of the `Transaction.createCredit` function and use this to set a variable `isSavedToDb = False`

and at some state (probably the closing event) check that variable and call the Save function if needed.